# Use components in Django Framework

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with using components in Django.

My project:
I'm working on a weblog that presents the current blog post. In the sidebar I want to include a component that lists ten latest posts and ten related posts. Each of these components are not only templates, but also include logic (which I rather would not include in the template using template tags).

What would be the best way to go to include such components?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django's class-based `DetailView` to display your blog post you can add extra information to be used in your template with `get_context_data()`, for example:

```
class BlogPostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = BlogPost

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogPostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['recent_posts'] = BlogPost.objects.filter(...)
        context['related_posts'] = BlogPost.objects.filter(...)
        return context
```

You can then use this information in your template like so:

```
{% for related_post in related_posts %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

If you need this information on multiple pages you can look into adding them via a context processor.